# how to read distributed files by using spark.read.csv() in Python command line window?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark

I can read local csv file in Python command line window by using spark.read.csv('csv path') ,but when I change the file to a distributed file, error occurs:

```
WARN FileStreamSink: Error while looking for metadata directory.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 476, in csv
    return self._df(self._jreader.csv(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o40.csv.
: java.io.IOException: Incomplete HDFS URI, no host: hdfs:///agriculture/historyClimate/59855.csv
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2669)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:547)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:545)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:545)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:359)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:618)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The spark version is 2.4.0, python version is 3.5, Hadoop is  2.6.0-cdh5.14.4.

Comment: try to add host and port to your path `hdfs://your_host:your_port/agriculture/historyClimate/59855.csv`

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace tells exactly what went wrong:

```
 An error occurred while calling o40.csv. : java.io.IOException: Incomplete HDFS URI, no host: hdfs:///agriculture/historyClimate/59855.csv
```

You've provided incorrect HDFS URI of the file. HDFS URI should look like:

```
hdfs://<host>:<port>/historyClimate/59855.csv
```

You can test whether URI is correct by using `hadoop` client:

```sh
hadoop fs -ls hdfs://<host>:<port>/historyClimate/59855.csv
```